# Crystal report gives "the system cannot find path specified" error when setting parameters

Tags: c#, visual-studio, crystal-reports

I am trying to export a crystal report to a pdf file that takes in a user-specified start-date and end-date. The report has default values for these parameters, and it exports without issue if I try it using those default values.

However, when i try to specify the parameters, the ExportToStream() function throws the error "the system cannot find path specified".

Code:

```
string startDateParm = "2018-01-01";
string endDateParm = "2018-01-31";

ReportDocument rd = new ReportDocument();
rd.Load(Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Reports/ReportExample.rpt")));
rd.SetParameterValue("Start Date", startDateParm);
rd.SetParameterValue("End Date", endDateParm);
Response.Buffer = false;

Stream stream = rd.ExportToStream(CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. I am still not sure what the exact issue was, but it had something to do with the default values for the parameters.
Steps to solve in VS2013:

1. Open report file in solution
2. Select "Main Report Preview"
3. Uncheck the checkbox labeled "Save data in the report".

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
rd.Load(Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Reports/ReportExample.rpt")));
```

to

```
rd.Load(Path.Combine(Server.MapPath(@"~/Reports/ReportExample.rpt")));
```

or

```
rd.Load(Path.Combine(Server.MapPath(@"{DRIVE:/{folder}/Reports/ReportExample.rpt")));
```

Comment: None of those work. I am not sure that the path string format is the issue, because it works correctly using the default parameter values when i don't call rd.SetParameterValue().

Comment: Have you tried to change the date format to a DateTime object and pass that as a parameter instead of the string.